# OpenCV with python connecting to external USB camera

Tags: python, opencv, camera, sdk, vision

Having issues connecting to external USB FLIR camera in OpenCV.

tried: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` the error message:

> error:
>
> OpenCV(3.4.1)
> C:\bld\opencv_1520732670222\work\opencv-3.4.1\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:356:
> error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Perhaps because issue is because we don't have the driver?

Comment: why do you even try to use a device without any drivers?

Comment: we are super new to this so not sure what is necessary to make this work

Comment: it's rather obvious that the first thing is to install the camera drivers. how else is your computer supposed to interact with the camera? it can't even tell the difference from a mouse

Comment: did you fix this... if so post an answer by answering it yourself.